Not able to debug using STM32F407G MCU in STM32CUBEIDE
Context: I did a project using this microcontroller and it works but i am not able to enter Debug Mode as it shows the following in the console screen:
STMicroelectronics ST-LINK GDB server. Version 7.8.0
Copyright (c) 2024, STMicroelectronics. All rights reserved.

Starting server with the following options:
        Persistent Mode            : Disabled
        Logging Level              : 1
        Listen Port Number         : 61234
        Status Refresh Delay       : 15s
        Verbose Mode               : Disabled
        SWD Debug                  : Enabled
        InitWhile                  : Enabled

Target no device found

Error in initializing ST-LINK device.
Reason: No device found on target.

I tried using the STM32 ST LINK UTILITY too but it shows:
 Can not connect to target!
                  If you're trying to connect to an STM32W1xx device, please select Normal or HotPlug mode from Target->Settings menu.
                  If you're trying to connect to a low frequency application , please select a lower SWD Frequency mode from Target->Settings menu.

i tried in all of the modes above but still can't bypass this. Even when i tried to perform Full Erase Chip,it shows the same.

I have checked in the Device Manager and have updated the Firmware too but there doesn't seem to be any problem there. I kindly request any solutions to this

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Which exact ST-Link model you have?Original from ST or clone? How you wired it?

ST-Link V2.J45.M31.Mine is a original model from ST.I wired it using a V3 cable.
